# fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors

I'm trying to test a library for an DHT22 "Temperature Sensor", but I got an error while including an internal arduino library from the `DHT.cpp` file

I got this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\DHT\DHT22.cpp:56:20:
fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory  #include <avr/io.h>
```

In the `DHT22.cpp`, this is the the block of error

```c
extern "C" {
 #include <avr/io.h>
 #include <avr/interrupt.h>
 #include <avr/pgmspace.h>
}
```

I got in the conclusion that the library is not finding the avr folder which is 
in  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr` I checked another built-in library servo.cpp and this is the include part

```c
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
```

but the last one works without errors, my question is why the DHT library is not importing the required files and the servo does ?

Comment: I updated, did you know about my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using some **old version of the library (from 2012)**.

The latest version, which does not contain the problematic "extern" block, can be found here:
https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library

(The default example works nicely with my Arduino Nano v3.0 and DHT22 sensor)